# c++ console screen size

Tags: c++, windows, console, iostream, setw

So I'm learning some stuff in College on C++, and the teacher and I got into a discussion on how to actually center text to the output screen. So my suggestion was to use `setw` but get the length of the string and the `size` of the console screen, do the algorithm and BAM we have truly centered text. He says the screen size is `80` but the screen can be resized, which doesn't work no matter what if the output is centered the the user starts resizing. Just a minor question I have, how to get the actual size of the console screen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int SCR_SIZE = 80;//some way of telling size

int main(){
   string randomText = "Hello User!";
   cout << setw( ( (80 / 2) + (randomText.length() / 2 ) ) ) 
        << randomText 
        << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Searched a little and found this bit

```
 #include <cstdlib>

 system("MODE CON COLS=25 LINES=22");
```

Would that work to set it on execution to make sure my size is what I want it to be? Just read through it so I'm not 100% positive if that in fact is a c++ library

Comment: You can't within the standard library. The program could very well not be using one.

Comment: Jerry, that deserves to be an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `#include <windows.h>` and call [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171.aspx). To use this, you'll need a Windows handle to your standard output stream, which you can retrieve with [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231.aspx).

Be aware that the resulting code will be Windows-specific (whereas your current code is portable, so it should run fine on Linux, Mac OS, *BSD, etc.)

Comment: yeah but if we were to make the code modular, we wouldn't want the windows library then. Is there some hack? Maybe outputting an empty string of whitespace to see how many there are until break?

Comment: added an update that I think would be good if it in fact is C++

Comment: The SetConsoleWindowInfo function should also be part of the solution.

Comment: @BenKey: Yes--unfortunately, you end up having to use quite a few console functions.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's impossible to make the console application window to be bigger than a bit more than half  of your screen, like it also is for cmd(command prompt). I'm just warning you that if you can't manually resize it to whatever size you want, you probably can't make it resize. Perhaps you want to try windows application or windows forms application?

Comment: This is incorrect. Simply hit Alt + Space to bring up the system menu. Then bring up the Properties dialog box. You can adjust the window size on the Layout pane. This can be done programmatically using the GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo and SetConsoleWindowInfo functions.